# Can't find 'longitude' in import wizard

Tags: geocoding

I have civicrm 4.7.31 on D7. From my old civicrm 4.1.1, I have exported the following fields in a csv file:

1) civicrm_contact (my external_identifier) in 4.7.31
2) geo_code_1 (latitude)
3) geo_code_2 (longitude)

Now, when I want to fill fields in the import contact wizard in 4.7.31, I find the latitude field, but there is no longitude field.
I have tried unsuccessfully to update the geocodes using the mapping function and Google in the Mapping and Geocoding section of the system settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure it is enabled under address settings. Go to Administer > Localization > Address Settings.

[image]

Comment: Andy, thanks. That did the trick. I would have searched for ways around that for hours - you saved me time.