# Contact Import Longitude missing in mapping

Tags: wordpress, import, field-mapping

I am trying to import contacts from one CIVI database to another however when doing the field mapping there is a map for latitude but not one for longitude. Am I missing something, if not is there any way to fix this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I concur this is missing from https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org so perhaps you could open an issue on https://lab.civicrm.org/groups/dev/-/issues

Answer (score 1):

See here: [Can't find 'longitude' in import wizard](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/24393/cant-find-longitude-in-import-wizard/24394#24394)

It should be available by default, so yes, open an issue to fix.